# How to filter data based on date?

Tags: javascript

I am having an array ,

```js
var data = [
    { id: 1, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2017-05-01]" },
    { id: 2, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2018-01-01]" },
    { id: 3, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 4, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2017-05-01]" },
    { id: 5, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2018-01-01]" },
    { id: 6, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 7, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2018-01-01]" },
    { id: 8, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 9, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2017-05-01]" }
    ];
    
    
data.forEach(function(result) {
   console.log(result.jobCategoryWithFromDate);
});
```

which gives the above result in console..

Here inside the foreach, i need to return the `jobCategoryWithFromDate` that has the latest date.

So expected result is, (same like below)..

```
ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2019-01-01]
PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2019-01-01]
SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2019-01-01]
```

The above is the expected result and no change in it, just need to filter the result and return `jobCategoryWithFromDate` returns unique value with latest date..

Despite of the duplicate names, the filter needs to be handled based on the date (latest)..

**Edit:**

I have already accepted answer but later only i came to know that it is not working in all scenario, I am sorry for not testing it completely..

Don't know whether my explanation gone wrong, but thing is if the user name is same then filter needs to be done based on date or otherwise unique user with any date needs to be displayed.

**Eg:**

```js
    var data = [
        { id: 1, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2017-05-01]" },
        { id: 2, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2018-01-01]" },
        { id: 3, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
        { id: 4, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2017-05-01]" },
        { id: 5, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2018-01-01]" },
        { id: 6, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
        { id: 7, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2018-01-01]" },
        { id: 8, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
        { id: 9, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2017-05-01]" },
        { id: 10, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "Jun.. / Junior  [valid from 2018-01-01]" },
        { id: 11, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "Usr.. / User [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
        { id: 12, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "Man.. / Manager [valid from 2017-05-01]" }
    ];

function extractDate(string){
  return string.match(/[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+/g);
}

var result = data.reduce((newestDates, currentItem)=>{
  if (newestDates.length===0) newestDates.push(currentItem);
  else {
    const dateDifference = new Date(extractDate(newestDates[0].jobCategoryWithFromDate)) - new Date(extractDate(currentItem.jobCategoryWithFromDate));
    
    if (dateDifference===0) newestDates.push(currentItem); // push items with the same date as newest found
    else if (dateDifference <= 0) newestDates = [currentItem]; // if item has newer date the original array gets replaced with one containing just this item
    // ignore case dateDifference >= 0 because we do not need to do anything with dates older than the newest found
  }
  return newestDates;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

Here in this snippet look at the last three values, which have different username but same date with previous records..

Here expected result is i need to get all the last three records along with above three, because they are different user, like

```
ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2019-01-01]
PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2019-01-01]
SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2019-01-01]
Jun.. / Junior  [valid from 2018-01-01]
Usr.. / User [valid from 2019-01-01]
Man.. / Manager [valid from 2017-05-01]
```

Comment: Any ideas or progress on it?

Comment: @Lain, Tried by storing the string into array like here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dBvoWQ but it is not expected.. I need to return the string by filtering inside foreach..

Comment: Can you influence the structure of the object? Like putting the from part (=date) in an own property? And preferably save it in ticks instead of yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: @Lain, No i cannot, it comes from backend and i just need to filter based on latest date and need to display each indivisual..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the date is in format `YYYY-MM-DD` you can just extract part of the string containing date from each element and create date object from it

**EDIT:** it seems that what you wanted was to get the last date for every user instead of just getting an array of entries with the latest dates, edited snippet to match it (you can edit part of regex extracting the name if you want a different comparison distinguishing between users)

```js
var data = [
    { id: 1, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2017-05-01]" },
    { id: 2, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2018-01-01]" },
    { id: 3, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 4, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2017-05-01]" },
    { id: 5, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2018-01-01]" },
    { id: 6, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 7, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2018-01-01]" },
    { id: 8, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 9, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2017-05-01]" },
    { id: 10, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "Jun.. / Junior  [valid from 2018-01-01]" },
    { id: 11, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "Usr.. / User [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 12, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "Man.. / Manager [valid from 2017-05-01]" }
];
    
function extractNameNDate(string){
  return [string.match(/^\w+/), string.match(/[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+/g)];
}

var result = data.reduce((newestDates, currentItem)=>{
  const [user, date] = extractNameNDate(currentItem.jobCategoryWithFromDate);
  if (newestDates[user]) {
    // compare dates for given user
    const [storedUser, storedDate] = extractNameNDate(newestDates[user].jobCategoryWithFromDate);
    const dateDifference = new Date(storedDate) - new Date(date);
    
    if (dateDifference <= 0) newestDates[user] = currentItem;
    
  } else {
    newestDates[user]=currentItem;
  }
  return newestDates;
},{});

result = Object.values(result);

console.log(result);
```

Here is an edited version to match entire first part of the string till the `[]` braces

```js
var data = [
    { id: 1, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "01-05 Data Specialist [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 2, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "01-05 Support [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 3, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "03-04 Technician [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 4, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "05 Engineer [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 5, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "05 Technician [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 6, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "05 Technologist [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 7, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "06 Engineer [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 8, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "06-07 Sr. Technician [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 9, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "Intern [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 10, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "06-07 Support  [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 11, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "06-07 Technologist [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 12, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "07 Engineer [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 13, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "08 Senior [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 14, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "08-09 Support [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 15, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "09 Senior [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 16, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "10-11 Principal [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 17, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "12-13 Sr. Principal [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 18, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "14 Vice President [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 19, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "15 President [valid from 2019-01-01]" }
];
    
function extractNameNDate(string){
  return [string.match(/[^\/]*/), string.match(/[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+/g)];
}

var result = data.reduce((newestDates, currentItem)=>{
  const [user, date] = extractNameNDate(currentItem.jobCategoryWithFromDate);
  if (newestDates[user]) {
    // compare dates for given user
    const [storedUser, storedDate] = extractNameNDate(newestDates[user].jobCategoryWithFromDate);
    const dateDifference = new Date(storedDate) - new Date(date);
    
    if (dateDifference <= 0) newestDates[user] = currentItem;
    
  } else {
    newestDates[user]=currentItem;
  }
  return newestDates;
},{});

result = Object.values(result);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: My expected result is ```ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2019-01-01]
PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2019-01-01]
SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2019-01-01]``` inside foreach.. Here your solution displays all the dates..

Comment: I need to get the result inside foreach, means while iterating it should check for the conditions and return the three strings like, ```ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2019-01-01]
PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2019-01-01]
SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2019-01-01]``` ...

Comment: I have edited my question can you help me, i just used my solution and it doesn't work if there are unique users with any date (match with previous user date also).. Can you help me in it..

Comment: Can you give me another part in the above solution, if the value is ```Surveyor [valid from 2017-05-01]``` and does not have ```../``` before the text??

Comment: Thanks for your update, but look at the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gd5jmqke/  i have replicated your code only but the expected result is it needs to give all the 7 items but it displays only 5 items.. See console for the results.. Each object has diffrent name but it displays only 5..

Comment: But if a string has ```../``` then whole array will have the same kind of data and if it does not have ```../``` then whole array will be like the given fiddle, so can you differentiate and provide me results and for both the cases for the same user, latest dated user needs to be displayed..

Comment: The thing that will not change is the starting ```[``` square bracket for every user there will be a valid from date and that start with square bracket you can compare both the question and fiddle, can we achieve the result with square bracket in regex??

Comment: Please help me out to extract the data before square bracket, i have tried this regex ```string.match(/S+\[+/), string.match(/[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+/g)``` but it is giving the last record only..

Comment: Hi, I am trying to make numbers at the front but your solution is not validating properly, For eg.., i am having 19 records totally and everything is valid but it is displaying only 12 records .. Look at the link here https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/VwwvxJM?editors=1112

Comment: that's because requirements changed, i used first part of the jobCategory as the unique identifier, the regex i've provided cannot match `-` character so it treats `01-05 Data Specialist` and `01-05 Support ` as the same category. I've added a more accurate capturing of the string part in front of the date, however now it will treat `07 Engineer` and `05 Engineer` as different professions, which may not be desired

Comment: Yes, but now i have given the requirement to support the numbers at the front also.. Can you give a modified example to achieve the same?? The rest part works fine but for number at the front and ```-``` between validation not working.. Please help me..

Comment: as mentioned in my comment from an hour ago, i already did, look at the bottom of the answer

Answer (score 1):

I would find the latest date first and then filter the array for objects with this date. This will return only the objects with the highest date:

```js
var data = [
  { id: 1, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2017-05-01]" },
  { id: 2, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2018-01-01]" },
  { id: 3, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
  { id: 4, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2017-05-01]" },
  { id: 5, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2018-01-01]" },
  { id: 6, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
  { id: 7, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2018-01-01]" },
  { id: 8, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
  { id: 9, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2017-05-01]" }
];

/* Add new property to data objects to store the "valid from" timestamp - Avoids parsing the text twice */
data.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
  var dateText = element.jobCategoryWithFromDate.match(/\[valid from (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\]$/)[1];
  array[index].fromDateTimestamp = +(new Date(dateText));
});

/* Get the highest value (the latest date) */
var max = data.reduce(function(currentMax, value) {
  return Math.max(currentMax, value.fromDateTimestamp);
}, 0);

/* Filter the data array to only include objects with the latest date */
var newData = data.filter(function(value) {
  return value.fromDateTimestamp === max;
});

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can apply regex to extract the date from string  `jobCategoryWithFromDate`. then sort by date, you will get latest results on top.

```
var data = [
    { id: 1, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2017-05-01]" },
    { id: 2, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2018-01-01]" },
    { id: 3, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 4, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2017-05-01]" },
    { id: 5, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2018-01-01]" },
    { id: 6, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 7, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2018-01-01]" },
    { id: 8, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 9, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2017-05-01]" }
    ];

var result= data.map(d => ({...d, date: d.jobCategoryWithFromDate.match(/(\d{1,4}([.\-/])\d{1,2}([.\-/])\d{1,4})/g)[0]}))..sort((a, b)=> new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a simple reduce, 
You could improve the reduce by storing the array and also the currentMaxDateTS instead of recalculate the timestamp in every iteration.

Don't hesitate if you need more explanation around this code snippet

```js
const data = [
    { id: 1, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2017-05-01]" },
    { id: 2, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2018-01-01]" },
    { id: 3, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 4, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2017-05-01]" },
    { id: 5, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2018-01-01]" },
    { id: 6, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 7, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2018-01-01]" },
    { id: 8, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 9, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2017-05-01]" }
    ];

// Function returning the date string inside  [valid from 2017-05-01]
const getDateFromJobCategory = (jobCategoryWithFromDate) =>  jobCategoryWithFromDate.match(/[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+/g);


const filteredData = data.reduce((acc, data) => {
  // Get data date in timestamp
  const dataDateString = getDateFromJobCategory(data.jobCategoryWithFromDate);
  const dataDateTS = new Date(dataDateString).getTime();
  // Get current max date in timestamp
  const currentMaxDate = getDateFromJobCategory(acc[0]);
  const currentMaxDateTS = new Date(currentMaxDate).getTime()

  return dataDateTS > currentMaxDateTS ? [data.jobCategoryWithFromDate] : dataDateTS === currentMaxDateTS ? [...acc, data.jobCategoryWithFromDate] : acc

}, ["[valid from 0001-01-01]"]);

   const finalResult = filteredData.forEach(jobCategoryWithFromDate => 
   console.log(jobCategoryWithFromDate))
```

Comment: I need to get the result inside foreach not like this, means while iterating it should check for the conditions and return the three strings like, ```ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2019-01-01]
PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2019-01-01]
SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2019-01-01]``` ...

Comment: I don't want array of string like yours, normal string.. Hope you get my point i am in the need to return it inside foreach..

Comment: I edited my answer, the result should be as asked :)
I just used the same algorithm and then forEach over it once that data is filtered.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a simple sort by extracting the date with regex, then use a recursive function to check if there are multiple dates the same:

```js
var data = [
    { id: 1, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2017-05-01]" },
    { id: 2, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2018-01-01]" },
    { id: 3, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 4, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2017-05-01]" },
    { id: 5, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2018-01-01]" },
    { id: 6, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 7, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2018-01-01]" },
    { id: 8, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2019-01-01]" },
    { id: 9, jobCategoryWithFromDate: "SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2017-05-01]" }
];

const getDate = date => +date.match(/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/g)[0].split('-').join('')

data = data.sort(({jobCategoryWithFromDate:date1}, {jobCategoryWithFromDate:date2}) => getDate(date2) - getDate(date1))

const getRecent = (data, i=0) => getDate(data[i].jobCategoryWithFromDate) === getDate(data[i + 1].jobCategoryWithFromDate) ? [data[i], ...getRecent(data, i+1)] : [data[i]]

getRecent(data).forEach(obj => console.log(obj))
```

Comment: My expected result is ```ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2019-01-01]
PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2019-01-01]
SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2019-01-01]``` inside foreach..

Comment: I need to get the result inside foreach, means while iterating it should check for the conditions and return the three strings like, ```ASSIST.. / Assistance [valid from 2019-01-01]
PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2019-01-01]
SEN.. / Senior [valid from 2019-01-01]``` ...

Comment: Is it not possible to do it inside foreach??  In my real application i am iterating this from template and calling a getter function and the function will get the each individual value like given and i need to filter it inside that function.. So here it needs to be inside foreach..

Comment: @ManirajfromKarur Im not quite sure i understand why you need a foreach, look at my code now.

Comment: To be simple, is it possible for you to provide solution inside foreach as like i have mentioned in question.. So inside foreach in ```result.jobCategoryWithFromDate``` we are getting string i need to check it inside this function itself.. Reason is i am not having the array mentioned in question and it is dynamic.. From template i am calling this function inside ng-repeat like {{ getData }} and this function only will have the code as foreach like mentioned in question.. So need to handle things inside foreach..

Comment: @ManirajfromKarur There is no need to use the foreach. I have literally built a solution that works, it would be much much harder and inefficient to use a foreach here.

Comment: Okay but it would better if you give me solution by handling things inside foreach because that is my complete requirement.. But its okay i will accept your solution for now..

Comment: `sort` is already a type of loop, along with `map`, `reduce`, and `forEach`, each with different uses and return values. I honestly don't know why you are striving to use a `forEach` here, when it is unable to return anything..

Comment: I am using angularjs app and there i am calling a function inside foreach and i am calling a getter method inside it and the getter method returns this above data which i displayed.. So i need to have the filter inside the getter method in my real application in which i will directly get ```result.jobCategoryWithFromDate``` values and i need to filter the data inside that function.. So only i am asking this way of approach..

Comment: You should call this code outside of the forEach, then loop the filtered data.

Comment: Edited my question and it doesn't work if i have unique records despite of date.. Say i am having only one record with some matching date with previous user but it is still showing only 2019 dates but the user is not repeated but has earlier date in 2017 which is also valid.. Can you check my edited question??